# Excel Parse by Casing of Letters

Tags: excel, parsing, excel-formula

```
HAVE            WANT1   WANT2
CLStephen Five  CL      Stephen Five
RTQQuent Lou X  RTQ     Quent Lou X
```

There is a data entry error on our school system, I have col 'HAVE' and wish to separate it into 'WANT1' and 'WANT2'

```
WANT1 = take the first n-1 CAPITAL letters
WANT2 = take the remaining letters
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=LET(α, LEFT(A2,MIN(IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,,97)),A2),""))-2), HSTACK(α,SUBSTITUTE(A2,α,)))
```

---

Formula only needs to fill down as it will spill on right!

---

Or, Try using the following formula with <kbd>TEXTSPLIT()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=TEXTSPLIT(REPLACE(A2,MIN(IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,,97)),A2),""))-1,0,"|"),"|")
```

---

Also you could try using one single dynamic array formula which would spill. Note dynamic array formulas don't work with **`Structured References`**

[image]

---

```
=DROP(REDUCE("",A2:A4, LAMBDA(α,φ, VSTACK(α, 
 TEXTSPLIT(REPLACE(φ,MIN(IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,,97)),φ),""))-1,0,"|"),"|")))),1)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Enter in `B2` and fill down:

```
=LET(
    lc, CHAR(SEQUENCE(26, , 97, 1)),
    split, MIN(FIND(lc, A2 & TEXTJOIN(, , lc))) - 2,
    HSTACK(LEFT(A2, split), MID(A2, split + 1, 99))
)
```

- `lc` generates a sequence of all the lower case letters.
- `split` finds the first lowercase letter and subtracts two (2).
- `LEFT` and `MID` use that position to generate the two `WANT`s

[image]

To enter a formula in just a single cell, and have the results `SPILL` down, you can try, in B2:

```
=LET(
    d, $A$2:$A$3,
    lc, CHAR(SEQUENCE(26, , 97, 1)),
    split, BYROW(
        d,
        LAMBDA(arr,
            MIN(FIND(lc, arr & TEXTJOIN(, , lc))) - 2
        )
    ),
    HSTACK(
        LEFT(d, split),
        MID(d, split + 1, LEN(d) - split)
    )
)
```

- `d` is the data range

*Note that this will not work if your results are in a `Table` because results that `SPILL` are not allowed. However, you can put separate formulas in `B2` and `C2` and the formulas would automatically spill down. Let me know if you need that configuration.*